# Push token is not generating when app is installed using archive ipa file.Token is generating when app is installed with binary file

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications, apn

i have created in-house production push certificate not able to generate push token with iPA creation .Token is generating when app is installed with binary file through iTunes and app is installed through Xcode. Why it is happen like this can any one knows?

Answer (score 0):

This is because we have 2 APNS environments - Production & Sandbox. When you generate a local build with Xcode, it gets auto signed with sandbox certs and you get connected to sandbox APNS. If your server side also using the sandbox push certificate, you will get a push with this device token.

To test production environment, you need right provisioning profile (profile with production key for .mobileprovision).

You can test APNS production environment building an AdHoc version of your App. The app will be using the production certificates and servers and it's purpose is exactly to test BEFORE you send it to AppleStore. Alternatively, you can test production pushes by downloading form App Store that is like more real time.